# Unicorn/Nginx process missing, socket open

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, nginx, capistrano, production-environment, unicorn

I am trying to deploy code using Capistrano, and it fails on `deploy:start` or `deploy:stop` because the Unicorn process is already killed. However if I try to `cap deploy:start`, I get a stderr claiming that `Address already in use - /tmp/my_app.socket`. How would this happen, and how might I get out of this mess?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Still not sure how this happens, but the following solution seems to work:

`lsof /tmp/my_app.socket` - lists the pids

`kill -9 pid` - (replace 'pid' with one of those listed)

Then `cap deploy:start` from the local terminal.

Comment: This actually saved my problem too!

Comment: This solved my problem... You should mark it as the right answer Micah Alcorn.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for someone to explain the issue, but I guess this is an effective solution. Just not sure that it is appropriate.

Comment: Do you discovered why it is being caused?