# Rails, Deploying With Capistrano to a VPS on Unicorn

Tags: deployment, capistrano, unicorn

I need help debugging the following issue. It's my first time deploying, and I haven't been able to come up with the solution.

```
  * 2012-12-05 18:37:44 executing `deploy:start'
  * executing "/etc/init.d/unicorn_blog start"
executing command
/etc/init.d/unicorn_blog: 24: kill: No such process
master failed to start, check stderr log for details
```

Here's the stderr

```
/.../unicorn/socket_helper.rb:140:in `initialize': Address already in use - /tmp/unicorn.my_app.sock (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

Comment: How'd you find stderr??

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have a zombie Unicorn process running with a PID different from the one that was recorded by init.d. I would try running `$ ps aux | grep unicorn` to find the zombie process, then `kill` it.

Answer (score 2):

Unsure how it works, but the following solution actually worked.

```
lsof /tmp/unicorn.my_app.socket
```

lists the pids

```
kill -9 pid
```

(replace 'pid' with one of those listed)

```
Then cap deploy:start from the local terminal.
```

source: [Unicorn/Nginx process missing, socket open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150245/unicorn-nginx-process-missing-socket-open)

Answer (score 1):

I had to

```
sudo rm /tmp/unicorn.my_app.sock
```

and

```
sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp start
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same error, and i fixed as below:

1. SSH to server where your project deploy to, and run these command 
   `ps -ef | grep unicorn` => list pid of unicorn. Find your process id of unocorn master.
   Replace pid on "unicorn.my_app.sock" with above pid.
2. Try to deploy again with capistrano.